# MS-Graph: Optimizing the download of content of DriveItem

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In our application we are storing a text file in Group Drive, and when loading the web page we are fetching the content of the drive item and displaying on the page. I want to optimize and cache the response if not changed so that every time if the user opens our app, the contents are served from cache if not modified on server.

We are using the [/content](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_downloadcontent) endpoint to download the content of the `DriveItem`.

The issue that I am facing currently is that first we need to do a `/content` call that returns a pre-authenticated URL, on which I need to do get call to read the content. This pre-authenticated URL is short lived and changes every time I do a `/content` call. Because of this the browser is not caching the response even though we get `Etag` from the pre-authenticated URL.

Is there some way to optimize the performance of content downloads call?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, this isn't really the intended scenario for  [`/content`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_downloadcontent.md). That said, you can pass in an `eTag` and receive a `HTTP 304 Not Modified` if the file hasn't changed.

You need to pass the last `eTag` in the `if-none-match` header of your `/content` request.

Comment: The /content endpoint does not returns the content it returns the pre-authenticated url with a 302 status code. While doing this calls the browser does not automatically redirect to the Url and the Url is new for every call(because its short lived url) so the etag does not work because the requested resource is not same as last time and browsers skip the if-none-match header.

Comment: To clarify, the browser isn't going to automatically handle this process. You would need to include the `if-none-match` in your calls to the drive and process the results. `/content` is indented to download the file locally, it wasn't intended to be used as a way to serve page content directly.